# C# POCO to a Stream/Byte[] and process while reading with a Silverlight 4 client over WCF

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0, stream

For me, one of the annoying parts of Silverlight is that it doesn't allow you to return a `Stream` directly, since Silverlight will turn it into a `Byte[]`, even when using `TransferMode.StreamedResponse`. Using that technique it is possible to process something like a `FileStream`, in a streaming fashion, from a Silverlight client (*see code below*).

However, I would like to do something similar with really large C# POCOs. If I could receive a `Stream` I could use something like XML serialization on both ends and process the records as they were read. However, since the return value has to be a `Byte[]` I have to read to the end of the array before I can process it. This method does at least allow me to provide some feedback to the user.

I came up with two possibilities on possible solutions. One would be to write my own serializer, or at least deserializer, where I process data as it is being read (I am thinking delimited text). The other thought would be to do some type of variable bit `Stream` class, which I believe would require a steep learning curve on my part. I am looking for any ideas or links on possibilities on how to process values in a `Byte[]` as they are read.

**Service Contract:**

```
public static class Action {
    public static string val = "http://tempuri.org/stream";
}

// Share contract between client and server
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileService {
#if SILVERLIGHT
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true, Action = Action.val, ReplyAction = Action.val)]
    IAsyncResult BeginReadFile(Message request, AsyncCallback callback, object AsyncState);
    system.ServiceMode.Channels.Message EndReadFile(IAsyncResult result);
#else
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true, Action = Action.val, ReplyAction = Action.val)]
    IAsyncResult BeginReadFile(string filePath, AsyncCallback callback, object AsyncState);
    system.IO.Stream EndReadFile(IAsyncResult result);
#endif
}

[DataContract(Name = "ReadFile", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public class StreamRequest
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string FileName;
}
```

**Service Implementation:**

```
public IAsyncResult BeginReadFile(string filePath, AsyncCallback callback, object AsyncState) {
    return new CompletedAsyncResult<Stream>(File.OpenRead(filePath));
}

public Stream EndReadFile(IAsyncResult result) {
    return ((CompletedAsyncResult<Stream>)result).Data;
}
```

**Client:**

```
public void ReadFile( string filePath ) {
    BackToUIThread backToUIThread = byteCount => {
        this.OnBytesReceived(this, new AsyncEventArgs<object>(byteCount));
    };

    StreamRequest request = new StreamRequest() { FileName = "C:\\test.txt" };
    Message mIn = Message.CreateMessage(
        _myFactory.Endpoint.Binding.MessageVersion, Action.val, request);

    _myService.BeginReadFile(mIn,
        (asyncResult) =>
        {
            Message mOut = _myService.EndReadFile(asyncResult);
            System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader r = mOut.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
            r.ReadToDescendant("ReadFileResult"); // move to stream
            r.Read(); // move to content

            int bytesRead = 1;
            long totalBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            do {
                bytesRead = r.ReadContentAsBase64(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                if (bytesRead > 0) {
                    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        backToUIThread, totalBytesRead);
                }
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
            r.Close();
            mOut.Close();                
        }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your Silverlight app pass in the offset and the number of bytes your want read to your service.

You could have something like

```
int offset = 0;  
int length = 1024;  
List<byte> bytes = new List<bytes>();  

_myService.ReadFileComplete += (s, e)=>  
{  
    bytes.Add(e.Result.Bytes);  
    if(asyncResult.Result.HasMore)  
    {  
        offset += length;  
        _myService.ReadFileAsync(fileName, offset, length);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        DoSomethingWithBytes(bytes);  
    }  
}

_myService.ReadFileAsync(fileName, offset, length);
```

Then on your WCF Service, just use the `Stream.Read` method with the given offset and length.

You could improve this by have the service return the next offset to be read.

Comment: I am already doing what you are suggesting in the async callback. I just left the movement of the buffer to byte[] out for brevity. What i am looking for is a way to process the buffer as I read it (i.e. deserialize as much as possible and keep track of the position for the next processing loop.) My issue is I don't know of a serializer that can do this (e.g. XML serializer requires the complete stream so it can match begin and end nodes).